# objective c subStringToIndex memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I use xcode 4.2 for 10.6, and ios 5, and have this strange memory leak reported when I profile the project using xcode.

Here is the code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
for (symbol in results) break;
[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];

[self beep];
NSString *upcScanned = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@", symbol.data]; //line 1
NSString * name = [self getItemName:upcScanned];
ProductNameDialog *dialog = [[ProductNameDialog alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductNameDialog" bundle:nil];

//dialog.upcScanned = [upcScanned substringToIndex:[upcScanned length] - 1];//line 2
[name release];
[self presentModalViewController:dialog animated:YES];
[dialog release];        
}
```

line2 was the line reported memory leak.

Comment: Add breakpoint or log in dialog release to see if it actually gets called.

Comment: Do you also release `upcScanned` in the dialog's `dealloc` method (or set it to `nil` since you haven't defined the instance variable)? `viewDidUnload` will not necessarily ever be called, it's typically only used in low memory conditions.

Comment: The leak detector reports the line that allocated the leaked object.  Statically-allocated strings are never considered leaks.  You are probably using upcScanned in some other method where you have an unbalanced retain.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical, and most probable conclusion is the the method `[self getItemName:upcScanned]` retains the passed in string but does not release it.